# How do I detect unwritten items in dynamodb2?

Tags: python, batch-processing, boto, amazon-dynamodb

I am migrating my code from `dynamodb` to `dynamodb2`. The code performs batch writes, and one of the main problems I am having is detecting unprocessed messages. My code continuously ingests messages from a queue and then inserts them in batches into a DynamoDB table. It appears that a huge chunk of items (about 20%) never make it into the table while I do not get any error messages about it. So my questions is how to catch when items do not get inserted and how to reprocess them? Here's a block of my `dynamodb` code that does that:

```
def do_batch_write(items,conn,table,diagn):
    batch_list = conn.new_batch_write_list()
    batch_list.add_batch(table, puts=items)
    iTry = 0
    rems = []
    while True:
        iTry = iTry + 1
        try:
            response = conn.batch_write_item(batch_list)
        except Exception, e:
            tRetry = 5
            log.error("Error while attempting batch_write_item, try %d, retrying after %d secs: %s" % (iTry, tRetry, str(e)))
            time.sleep(tRetry)
            continue

        unprocessed = response.get('UnprocessedItems', None)
        if not unprocessed:
            if len(items) == 1 and diagn:
                log.info("Trivial batch processed")
            break
        batch_list = conn.new_batch_write_list()
        unprocessed_list = unprocessed[table.name]
        items = []
        for u in unprocessed_list:
            item_attr = u['PutRequest']['Item']
            item = table.new_item( attrs=item_attr)
            items.append(item)
        rems.append(len(items))
        batch_list.add_batch(table, puts=items)

    return iTry
```

Here's a block of `dynamodb2` code that I am trying to modify to handle unprocessed/abandoned items.

```
with table.batch_write() as batch:
    while True:
         m = inq.read()
         mStr = json.dumps(m)
         pid = m['primaryId']
         sid = m['secondaryId']
         item_data = {"primaryId" : pid, "secondaryId"] : sid, "message"] : mStr}
         batch.put_item(data=item_data)
```

I looked at [**this page**](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migrations/dynamodb_v1_to_v2.html#batch-writes) but found no help there. Can you help me figure out how to modify it? Thx

**UPDATE**: I am still having a problem with missing items. I modified the above block as follows:

```
i = 0
with table.batch_write() as batch:
    while True:
         m = inq.read()
         i = i + 1
         mStr = json.dumps(m)
         pid = m['primaryId']
         sid = m['secondaryId']
         item_data = {"primaryId" : pid, "secondaryId"] : sid, "message"] : mStr}
         batch.put_item(data=item_data)

         if i == 25:
             batch.resend_unprocessed()
             i = 0
```

However, what I found after careful logging of all the incoming data (the log print statements were not included in the code snippet above to save space), I saw, at least in one case, the following:

1. A set of about 20 consecutively ingested messages get added to the batch by `put_item`
2. When `resend_unprocessed()` is called it reports 0 unprocessed items
3. When I try to retrieve any of the 20 messages from the DDB table, they are nowhere to be found

So it appears that I can't really trust `boto` when it says that it successfully wrote items into a table. Looks like a bug, or is this some sort of "feature" of `dynamodb2`?

One thing that I forgot to mention before: I have several identical "worker" processes running in parallel on the same AWS EC2 instance reading from the same input queue and writing into the same Dynamo table. I create several of them to keep up with the volume of incoming data. I was under the impression that they should not be fighting for access to the table and that even if there is some sort of conflict between them, it has to be resolved "under the `dynamodb` hood". Even if that causes some of the items to somehow get dropped, it should not be reporting in `resend_unprocessed()` that everything has been successfully processed.

Comment: What observation of yours makes you say that "It appears that a huge chunk of items (about 20%) never make it into the table"?

Comment: I logged messages that were captured before I batch-wrote them into DDB, then tried to retrieve them from DDB. About 20% of them were not found. This was done on a test set of about 20000 messages, so it's not a "hiccup".

Comment: I was considering mere delays in their appearance, but probably Sony's answer hits the nail much better.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this is possible.

Batch write may not be able to write "all" items. In this case API succeeds, but the unwritten items are indicated as "UnprocessedItems" in the response. You need to look into this and retry these items again.

Typical reason for this happening is your table throughput exceeding (there may be other reasons as well).

Adding the relevant code snippet (thanks to the below gist):

```
while True:
    response = dynamodb_conn.batch_write_item(batch_list)
    unprocessed = response.get('UnprocessedItems', None)
    if not unprocessed:
        break
    batch_list = dynamodb_conn.new_batch_write_list()
    unprocessed_list = unprocessed[table_name]
    items = []
    for u in unprocessed_list:
        item_attr = u['PutRequest']['Item']
        item = dynamodb_table.new_item(
                attrs=item_attr
        )
        items.append(item)
    batch_list.add_batch(dynamodb_table, puts=items)
```

These additional readings will tell you the details - last one is a python code as well.

1. [BatchWriteItem - Amazon DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html)
2. [The correct way of using DynamoDB BatchWriteItem with boto](http://agiletesting.blogspot.in/2012/05/correct-way-of-using-dynamodb.html)
3. Python gist for this: https://gist.github.com/griggheo/2698152

Comment: If you, instead of just give a link to the solution, add an excerpt of the code which solves the issue (may contain "..." for the boring parts) and reply on this comment so that I notice the change, you will get my ⁺¹ ;-)

Comment: I am not sure this will work for me. It looks like the sample above is `ddb` not `ddb2`, and I am moving from the former to the latter. Can you provide another sample where the unprocessed control is hooked to `batch_write()` of `ddb2`. Thx

Answer (score 1):

the above answer is not related to dynamodb2.

i am using resend_unprocessed() and it actually works.

boto logs:

```
2015-11-03 08:45:13,427 INFO: table.resend_unprocessed (1491): 1424-MainThread: Re-sending 11 unprocessed items.
2015-11-03 08:45:13,427 INFO: table.resend_unprocessed (1502): 1424-MainThread: Sending 11 items
2015-11-03 08:45:13,428 DEBUG: connection._mexe (910): 1424-MainThread: Method: POST
2015-11-03 08:45:13,428 DEBUG: connection._mexe (911): 1424-MainThread: Path: /
2015-11-03 08:45:13,428 DEBUG: connection._mexe (912): 1424-MainThread: Data: {"RequestItems": {"user_feed": [{"PutRequest": XXXXXXXXXXXXX }
2015-11-03 08:45:13,429 DEBUG: connection._mexe (913): 1424-MainThread: Headers: {'Host': 'dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0', 'Content-Length': '1540', 'X-Amz-Target': 'DynamoDB_20120810.BatchWriteItem'}

2015-11-03 08:45:13,453 DEBUG: layer1._retry_handler (2746): 1424-MainThread: Saw HTTP status: 200
2015-11-03 08:45:13,453 DEBUG: layer1._retry_handler (2778): 1424-MainThread: Validating crc32 checksum for body: {"UnprocessedItems":{}}
2015-11-03 08:45:13,453 DEBUG: layer1.make_request (2733): 1424-MainThread: {"UnprocessedItems":{}}
2015-11-03 08:45:13,453 INFO: table.resend_unprocessed (1506): 1424-MainThread: 0 unprocessed items left
```

but as written AT http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/dynamodb2.html

"Used by Table as the context manager for batch writes.

You likely don’t want to try to use this object directly."

you should not use resend_unprocessed. context manager do it when processing your requests. (look at your boto logs )

like:

```
2015-11-03 08:43:43,551 INFO: table.handle_unprocessed (1483): 1424-MainThread: 23 items were unprocessed. Storing for later.

2015-11-03 08:43:43,551 INFO: table.resend_unprocessed (1506): 1424-MainThread: 51 unprocessed items left
```